# Can't find BLOB datatype on Hasura

Tags: postgresql, image, graphql, hasura

I tried to add a new column from datatype BLOB to hold images but I can't find this datatype. 
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `bytea`.

[image]

Docs: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/postgresql-types.html

Comment: No, there is a difference between blob and bytea

Comment: @idanahal Postgres does not have a BLOB type. For binary strings, you use `bytea`. See: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB